# How I can change a list using 'item' to dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to run a code from Github. In the following piece of the code:

```
def read_table(table_file):
    
        table = dict()
        
        with open(table_file, 'rb') as handle:
            while True:
                   try:
                           table = pickle.load(handle)
                   except EOFError:
                           break
        
        f_set=set()
        
        for k,v in list.items():
            for feature in v[DATA]:
                f_set.add(feature)
               
        return table , f_set
```

I got this error:
**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'**
How can I change the list to dict in this code? Can anyone please help me?

I try to change the list using filter or dir() function but I got new errors.

Comment: Maybe try:   `for k,v in table.items():` ??

Comment: It's worth noting that `table` could contain any kind of data, after you load it from your pickle file. Though since you don't actually use it later in the code, that shouldn't actually matter.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to iterate over `list`. `list` is a builtin type in Python. What you probably meant to do is iterate over `table`, which is a dictionary and *does* have a `.items()` method.

Here's the revised snippet:

```
import pickle

def read_table(table_file):
    table = dict()
    with open(table_file, 'rb') as handle:
        while True:
            try:
                table = pickle.load(handle)
            except EOFError:
                break
    f_set = set()

    for k, v in table.items():
        for feature in v[DATA]:
            f_set.add(feature)

    return table, f_set
```